# Get start and end date of a week from date range in PHP

Tags: php, date

I am using below code to get week start (Monday) and end date (Sunday) from given date range.

```
function getWeekDates($date, $start_date, $end_date) {
        $week =  date('W', strtotime($date));
        $year =  date('Y', strtotime($date));
        $month =  date('M', strtotime($date));
        $from = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$year}-W{$week}")); //Returns the date of monday in week
        if($from < $start_date) $from = $start_date;
        $to = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$year}-W{$week}-7"));   //Returns the date of sunday in week
        if($to > $end_date) $to = $end_date;
        $d =  date('d', strtotime($from));
        return ['week'=>$month."-".$d,'st'=>$from,'end'=>$to];
    }  

    function getWeekDatesArr($start_date = null , $end_date = null) {
        $arr = [];
        for($date = $start_date; $date <= $end_date; $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date. ' + 7 days'))) {
            $list = getWeekDates($date, $start_date, $end_date);
            $arr[$list['week']] = ['start'=>$list['st'],'end'=>$list['end']];
        }
        return $arr;
    }

    $start_date = '2019-10-14';
    $end_date = '2020-01-05';
    $dates = getWeekDatesArr($start_date, $end_date);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($dates);
```

[See code and Preview here](https://3v4l.org/cOXEL)

In output last start and end date is wrong. it not showing for next year

```
[Dec-23] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2019-12-23
            [end] => 2019-12-29
        )

    [Dec-14] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2019-10-14
            [end] => 2019-01-06
        )
```

Comment: It's messing up on `2019-12-30`. If you `echo "$week - $year - $month - $from\n";`, you get `01 - 2019 - Dec - 2018-12-31`, because while the date is at the end of 2019, it's technically the first week of 2020.

Comment: @aynber what is solution?

Comment: That I'm not sure about. I can see the problem, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Using the DateTime class might help a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier and clearer to use the [DateTime class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

```
<?php
$start_date = '2019-10-14';
$end_date = '2020-01-05';

$date = date_create($start_date);
$end = date_create($end_date);

$dates = [];
while($date < $end){
  $key = $date->format('M-d');
  $dates[$key] = [
    'start' => $date->format('Y-m-d'),
    'end'   => $date->modify('next Sunday')->format('Y-m-d')
  ];
  $date->modify('next Monday'); 
}

//test output
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($dates);
```

**Note:**
The key as 'M-d' can cause problems. For a period of several years, the keys are no longer unique. It is better to include the year in the key as well.